# LibGDX: low fps while running multiple instances

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I've been playing with libGDX, because I want to develop a multiplayer game with my friend. My recent problem did come up while testing the communication with multiple clients. I run all the clients and the server from one computer. If I run 'n' clients, all the clients run on exactly 60/'n' fps. Why?

The source code of the project is available at: http://github.com/FBalazs/Yellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game loop that libgdx uses by default renders at a fixed rate I find it to be about 60fps if you are running on desktop you can set the foreground and background FPS in the desktop application main method.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "Game Name";
    cfg.fullscreen = false;
    cfg.vSyncEnabled = false;
    cfg.foregroundFPS = 120; // Change the FPS
    cfg.width = 1280;
    cfg.height = 720;

    new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
}
```

I believe you can also use [Continuous & non continuous rendering](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-%26-non-continuous-rendering) but I have not tried it as of yet.

Comment: I know about these technics, but not the performence was the problem. Turning off the vertical sync sovled the problem, but i don't know why. I also don't know what vsync really is.

Comment: vSync is used to prevent screen tearing by syncing the fps with the screen refresh rate.